# Conditional Html.Action Render Based on Service / Controller Response

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, conditional-statements, ninject, html.actionlink

Our ASP.NET MVC 5.0 App is using Users and Roles from ASP.NET, but extending it with custom Permissions. They require very granular and dynamic authorized attributes and link rendering, based upon what specific permission a user's Role has.

For example:

Permission Name : Products.Edit 
User:             MyUser
UserRoles:        Admin, ProductsAdmin
Role Permissions: X,Y,Z... Products.Edit...n

I have a service that takes in a list of roles like so:

```
public interface PermissionServiceInterface
{
    bool HasPermission(string permissionNameIdentifier, params string[] roles);
}
```

I have created a custom Authenticate attribute using Ninject that can be applied to either a controller or action like this:

```
[PermissionAuthorize("Products.Edit")]
public ProductsController()
{
}
```

Now I would like to conditionally render a link in a view based on whether the users roles has a specific permission.

Something like:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create Product", "Create").If("Products.Edit")
```

And using a static extension method like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString If(this MvcHtmlString value, string permission)
{
    return permissionService.HasPermission(permission) ? value : 
    MvcHtmlString.Empty;
}
```

The problem is that you cannot inject dependencies into static extension classes.

Which leaves me with a few options, but all seem overkill.

1. Create custom IPrinciple to include User.HasPermission("permission"). This is alot of work.
2. Put this into a razor @helper function that calls a controller to evaluate this condition. But Views should have no knowledge of controllers, so this goes against the whole principle of MVC.
3. Put this into a regular class / method somewhere, but now Ninject needs to be setup to be aware of and instantiate these classes.
4. Use the static extension class, but use ninject container as a service locator to resolve the dependancy.

Are any of these ideal? Are there any other simpler ways of doing this?

Thanks guys!